How to fix ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE error when using Model.create with sequelize in MySQL when terminal shows models have been made?
I have read that MySQL does not support autoincrementing values with bulk inserts (bulkCreate() function) so I used a looping create() function instead to test whether it will work that way.
NOTE: if you see treeSeedData and suppliersData those are just arrays of objects (the actual data I am inserting with fields defined in the model). They have key:value pairs in them except for the primary keys seed_id and supplier_id.For treeSeedData the seedcompany_name is swapped out for seedcompany_id using the utility functions.
Here are the files
//server.js

const sequelize = require("./config/sequelize.js")
const {TreeSeed,Supplier,treeSeedData,suppliersData} = require("./models")
const {createSupplierRef,addSupplierIdToSeeds} = require("./utility_funcs/utilities.js")

const authenticate = async () => {
   try{
      await sequelize.authenticate();
      console.log("authentication successful")
   }catch(error){
      console.error('Unable to connect to the database:',error)
   }
}
authenticate();
const makeModels = async () => {
   try{
      await sequelize.sync({force:true});
      console.log("All models made")
   }catch(error){
      console.error('Unable to connect to make tables:',error)
   }
};
makeModels();

const insertSupplier = async () =>{
   try{
      const arrayLen = suppliersData.length
      let supplier;
      let binArr = [];
      for(let i=0; i < arrayLen; i++){
        supplier = await Supplier.create(suppliersData[i])
        binArr = [...supplier.dataValues]
      }
    console.log("Suppliers data successfully inserted")
    return binArr;
   }catch(error){
      console.error("Could not insert supplier records:",error)
      return [];

   }
};


const insertTreeSeed = async (suppliers) =>{
   try{
      //swap out logic
      const supplierRefObj = createSupplierRef(suppliers)
      const newTreeSeedData = addSupplierIdToSeeds(treeSeedData,supplierRefObj)
      const arrayLen = newTreeSeedData.length
      let treeSeed;
      for(let i=0; i < arrayLen; i++){
        treeSeed = await TreeSeed.create(suppliersData[i])
      }
       console.log("Treeseed data successfully inserted")
   
   }catch(error){
      console.error("Could not insert tree seed records:",error)
   }
}
insertSupplier().then((suppliers)=>insertTreeSeed(suppliers))


//utiliy_funcs/utilites.js

function createSupplierRef(suppliersData){//for orders
    const supplierLookup = {}
    const supplierDataCopy = [...suppliersData]
   const creationLookup = supplierDataCopy.map((supplier)=>{
      const supplierCpy = {...supplier}
     supplierLookup[supplierCpy.supplier_name] = supplierCpy.supplier_id
    })

    //{fothergill : 14}
    return supplierLookup
}

function addSupplierIdToSeeds(treeSeedData,supplierLookup){//switch out shape in bird_orders
    const newSeedArray = treeSeedData.map((seed)=>{
      const seedCpy = {...seed}
      seedCpy.seedcompany_id = supplierLookup[seedCpy.seedcompany_name]
      delete seedCpy.seedcompany_name
      return seedCpy
    })
    return newSeedArray
  }

  module.exports = {createSupplierRef,addSupplierIdToSeeds}

//index.js

const {TreeSeed,treeSeedData} = require("./tree_seeds.js")
const {Supplier,suppliersData} = require("./supplier.js");

Supplier.hasMany(TreeSeed,{
    foreignKey: 'seedcompany_id'
});
TreeSeed.belongsTo(Supplier,{
    foreignKey: 'seedcompany_id'
})
module.exports = {TreeSeed,treeSeedData,Supplier,suppliersData};


//tree_seeds.js

const {DataTypes, Model} = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("../config/sequelize.js")

class TreeSeed extends Model {
  
    
}
TreeSeed.init({
    
    seed_id:{
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    },
    common_name:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    species_name:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
        unique:true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    family:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
        allowNull: false
    },
    seed_cost_incl_VAT:{
        type: DataTypes.DOUBLE(4,2),
        allowNull: false
    },
    quantity_in_stock:{
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    seed_number_per_pack:{
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    colour:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
        allowNull: false
    },
    hardiness:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
        allowNull: false
    },
    soil_type:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING(60),
        allowNull: false
    },
    soil_acidity:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING(60),
        allowNull: false
    },
    description:{
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    },
    tree_image1:{
        type: DataTypes.BLOB,
        allowNull: false
    },
    tree_image2:{
        type: DataTypes.BLOB,
        
    },
    tree_image3:{
        type: DataTypes.BLOB,       
     },
    seedcompany_id:{
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references:{
           model: 'Supplier',
           key: 'supplier_id'
        }
    }
    }

    ,{
     sequelize,
     timestamps: false,
     freezeTableName: true

})
 
module.exports = {TreeSeed,treeSeedData};

//supplier.js

const {DataTypes, Model} = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("../config/sequelize.js")

class Supplier extends Model {
  
}

Supplier.init({
    supplier_id:{
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
        
       
    },
    supplier_name:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING(60),
        allowNull: false
    },
},{
    sequelize,
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,

})

module.exports =  {Supplier,suppliersData};

//Error in the terminal when node server.js is ran

//The catch block in insertSuppplier creates the ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE error that then causes //the null violation errors in insertTreeSeed from what it looks like

Could not insert supplier records: Error
   
      at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:343:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:316:9)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:253:10) {
    code: 'ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE',
    errno: 1146,
    sqlState: '42S02',
    sqlMessage: "Table 'items_dev_db.Supplier' doesn't exist",
    sql: 'INSERT INTO `Supplier` (`supplier_name`) VALUES (?);',
    parameters: [ 'Kent & Stowe' ]
  },
  original: Error: Table 'items_dev_db.Supplier' doesn't exist
      at Packet.asError 
      at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:343:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:316:9)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:253:10) {
    code: 'ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE',
    errno: 1146,
    sqlState: '42S02',
    sqlMessage: "Table 'items_dev_db.Supplier' doesn't exist",
    sql: 'INSERT INTO `Supplier` (`supplier_name`) VALUES (?);',
    parameters: [ 'Kent & Stowe' ]
  },
  sql: 'INSERT INTO `Supplier` (`supplier_name`) VALUES (?);',
  parameters: [ 'Kent & Stowe' ]
}
Could not insert tree seed records: ValidationError [SequelizeValidationError]: notNull Violation: TreeSeed.common_name cannot be null,
notNull Violation: TreeSeed.species_name cannot be null,
notNull Violation: TreeSeed.family cannot be null,
notNull Violation: TreeSeed.seed_cost_incl_VAT cannot be null,
notNull Violation: TreeSeed.quantity_in_stock cannot be null,
notNull Violation: TreeSeed.seed_number_per_pack cannot be null,
notNull Violation: TreeSeed.colour cannot be null,
notNull Violation: TreeSeed.hardiness cannot be null,
notNull Violation: TreeSeed.soil_type cannot be null,
notNull Violation: TreeSeed.soil_acidity cannot be null,
notNull Violation: TreeSeed.description cannot be null,
notNull Violation: TreeSeed.tree_image1 cannot be null{
  errors: [
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'TreeSeed.common_name cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'common_name',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [TreeSeed],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    },
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'TreeSeed.species_name cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'species_name',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [TreeSeed],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    },
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'TreeSeed.family cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'family',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [TreeSeed],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    },
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'TreeSeed.seed_cost_incl_VAT cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'seed_cost_incl_VAT',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [TreeSeed],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    },
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'TreeSeed.quantity_in_stock cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'quantity_in_stock',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [TreeSeed],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    },
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'TreeSeed.seed_number_per_pack cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'seed_number_per_pack',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [TreeSeed],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    },
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'TreeSeed.colour cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'colour',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [TreeSeed],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    },
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'TreeSeed.hardiness cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'hardiness',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [TreeSeed],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    },
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'TreeSeed.soil_type cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'soil_type',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [TreeSeed],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    },
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'TreeSeed.soil_acidity cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'soil_acidity',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [TreeSeed],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    },
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'TreeSeed.description cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'description',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [TreeSeed],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    },
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'TreeSeed.tree_image1 cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'tree_image1',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [TreeSeed],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    }
  ]
}

Executing (default): SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME as constraint_name,CONSTRAINT_NAME as constraintName,CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA as constraintSchema,CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA as constraintCatalog,TABLE_NAME as tableName,TABLE_SCHEMA as tableSchema,TABLE_SCHEMA as tableCatalog,COLUMN_NAME as columnName,REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA as referencedTableSchema,REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA as referencedTableCatalog,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME as referencedTableName,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME as referencedColumnName FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where TABLE_NAME = 'Supplier' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME!='PRIMARY' AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA='items_dev_db' AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `TreeSeed`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Supplier`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Supplier`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Supplier` (`supplier_id` INTEGER auto_increment , `supplier_name` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`supplier_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Supplier`
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `TreeSeed`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TreeSeed` (`seed_id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment UNIQUE , `common_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL UNIQUE, `species_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL UNIQUE, `family` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, `seed_cost_incl_VAT` DOUBLE PRECISION(4,2) NOT NULL, `quantity_in_stock` INTEGER NOT NULL, `seed_number_per_pack` INTEGER NOT NULL, `colour` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, `hardiness` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, `soil_type` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, `soil_acidity` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, `description` TEXT NOT NULL, `tree_image1` BLOB NOT NULL, `tree_image2` BLOB, `tree_image3` BLOB, `seedcompany_id` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (`seed_id`), FOREIGN KEY (`seedcompany_id`) REFERENCES `Supplier` (`supplier_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `TreeSeed`
All models made 

> Blockquote

(NOTE IT SAYS ABOVE THE MODELS HAVE BEEN MADE)

//sequelize.js

const {Sequelize} = require("sequelize");
const { isOmittedExpression } = require("typescript");
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development' ;
const pathToEnvFile = `${__dirname}/../.env.${environment}`;
require("dotenv").config({path: pathToEnvFile})


const optionsObj = {}
let db_name;
let db_username;
let db_password;
const dialect = "dialect", host = "host", max = "max", acquire = "acquire", idle = "idle", timezone = "timezone", port = "port", define = "define", omitNull = "omitNull"
optionsObj[dialect] =  "mysql"
optionsObj[omitNull] =  true

if(environment === 'development'){
  db_name = process.env.DEV_MYSQLDATABASE 
  db_username = process.env.DEV_USERNAME
  db_password = process.env.DEV_PASSWORD 
  optionsObj[host] = process.env.DEV_HOST
  optionsObj[max] = process.env.DEV_MAX
  optionsObj[acquire] = process.env.DEV_ACQUIRE
  optionsObj[idle] = process.env.DEV_IDLE
  optionsObj[timezone] = process.env.DEV_TIMEZONE 
  optionsObj[port] =  process.env.DEV_PORT 

}else{
    db_name = process.env.TEST_MYSQLDATABASE
    db_username = process.env.TEST_USERNAME
    db_password = process.env.TEST_PASSWORD 
    optionsObj[host] = process.env.TEST_HOST
    optionsObj[max] = process.env.TEST_MAX
    optionsObj[acquire] = process.env.TEST_ACQUIRE 
    optionsObj[idle] = process.env.TEST_IDLE
    optionsObj[timezone] = process.env.TEST_TIMEZONE 
    optionsObj[port] =  process.env.TEST_PORT 

}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    db_name,
    db_username,
    db_password,
    optionsObj
   
);

module.exports = sequelize;


The error mesaage is clear: a table the orm expects to be there, is not there. A typical reason would be that the migration creates the table in database A, but the orm looks for it in database B.

@Shadow Okay I have created a development database but the test database is empty. I can authenticate and connect to the development database with the usual host, username and password. with the actual values stored behind environment variables. So how do I fix the issue? I am new to sequelize.

You need to run the migrations again and again for each environment in your route to live process.

@Shadow I have added my sequelize.js file to the question to add more context (see above). I'm sorry for asking again but I am new to databases and orm. I want to insert the data into this mysql database so I can pull from it later with PHP into my website. I don't understand what you mean by run migrations again and again. Could you please explain in a more simplified way and/or point me to what I should search for online to read about it?

@Shadow I actually looked into migrations and have created 2 migration files but now there is a new error -> code: 'ER_FK_CANNOT_DROP_PARENT',
errno: 3730,
sqlState: 'HY000',
sqlMessage: "Cannot drop table 'Suppliers' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'TreeSeeds_ibfk_1' on table 'TreeSeeds'.",
sql: 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Suppliers;',

Seems like you trying to drop a parent table before the child one. Try to reverse their order
